# What is the earliest possible turn to activate each quest?

Tags: hearthstone

Since Un'Goro there are [quest cards](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Quest_(ability)) in Hearthstone, that, after played, require a certain amount of specific actions to be performed to activate an effect. Each class currently has one quest.

What is the earliest turn as starting/second player for each class to activate their respective quest?
This could include a random hit like [Swashburglar](http://www.hearthpwn.com/cards/42046-swashburglar) grabbing a spell or [Thoughtsteal](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Thoughtsteal) acquiring a deathrattle minion.

Comment: I think having this question for all 9 quests is probably going to make an answer too long. That said, the rogue quest can be completed turn 1 if you're really lucky.

Comment: @Chris Hayes indeed :D Take a look below ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am just talking about the standard format.
And I cheated a bit :D Sometimes your opponent needs to help you out a bit ;)

**Druid** Turn 5 complete, turn 6 playing [Barnabus](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Barnabus_the_Stomper)

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Jungle_Giants):*** Summon 5 minions with 5 or more Attack.

As first Player (no [coin](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Coin)):

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 1x [Innervate](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Innervate) + 5-Attack 3,4-drop (e.g. [Ancient Brewmaster](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Ancient_Brewmaster))
3. turn: 5-Attack 3-drop
4. turn: 1x Innervate 2x5-Attack 3-drop
5. turn: 5-Attack 3,4,5-drop (e.g. [Verdant Longneck](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Verdant_Longneck))
6. Play Barnabus

As second Player (coin):

1. turn: Quest + Coin + 1x Innervate + 5-Attack 3-drop (e.g. [Elder Longneck](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Elder_Longneck))
2. turn: 1x Innervate + 5-Attack 3,4-drop (e.g. Ancient Brewmaster)
3. turn: 5-Attack 3-drop
4. turn: 5-Attack 3,4-drop
5. turn: 5-Attack 3,4,5-drop (e.g. Verdant Longneck)
6. Play Barnabus

   ---

**Hunter**

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Marsh_Queen):*** Play seven 1-Cost minions. Turn 4 complete, turn 5 Queen [Carnassa](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Queen_Carnassa)

With or without coin:

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 2x 1-drop ([Jeweled Macaw](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Jeweled_Macaw)) (getting one drops or drawing them)
3. turn: [Stampede](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Stampede) + 2x 1-drop (getting 1-drops or drawing them)
4. turn: 3x 1-drop
5. turn: Queen Carnassa

   ---

**Mage** With coin turn 2 complete, turn 4 [Time Warp](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Time_Warp)
*edit: Thanks to scenia, you can of course complete the quest already in turn 2*

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Open_the_Waygate):*** Cast 6 spells that didn't start in your deck.

As first Player (no coin):

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 6x [Primordial Glyph](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Primordial_Glyph)) into Primoridal Glyph
3. turn: wait, Opponent plays [Arcane Golem](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Arcane_Golem)
4. turn: Timewarp

As second Player (coin):

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 5x Primordial Glyph into Primoridal Glyph
3. turn: wait
4. turn: Coin + Time Warp

   ---

**Paladin** Turn 4 complete, turn 5 [Galvadon](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Galvadon)

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Last_Kaleidosaur):*** Cast 6 spells on your minions.

With or without coin:

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: [Stonetusk Boar](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Stonetusk_Boar) + [Blessing of Wisdom](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Blessing_of_Wisdom) (attack with Boar)
3. turn: 3x 1-Mana Spell
4. turn: 2x 1-Mana Spell
5. Galvadon

---

**Priest** Turn 3 complete, turn 4 [Amara](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Amara,_Warden_of_Hope)

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Awaken_the_Makers):*** Summon 7 Deathrattle minions.

As first Player (no coin):

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 2x [Crystalline Oracle](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Crystalline_Oracle) (both into Innervate) + Opponent plays [Naturalize](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Naturalize)
3. turn: Innervate + 5x 1-drops
4. turn: Innervate + Amara

As second Player (coin):

1. turn: Quest + Coin + 1-drop (Crystalline Oracle into Innervate)
2. turn: 2x 1-drop (Crystalline Oracle into 1-drop)
3. turn: 3x 1-drop
4. turn: 1x 1-drop + Innervate + Amara

   ---

**Rogue** Turn 1 complete, turn 1 [Crystal Core](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Crystal_Core)

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Caverns_Below):*** Play four minions with the same name.

As first Player (no coin):

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: [Swashburglar](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Swashburglar) (into [Shadowstep](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Shadowstep)) + 3x Shadowstep + 3x Swashburglar + 1x [Counterfeit Coin](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Counterfeit_Coin) + 1x [Preparation](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Preparation) + 1x Crystal Core

As second Player (coin):

1. turn: Quest + Coin + Swashburglar (into Shadowstep) + 3x Shadowstep + 3x Swashburglar + 2x Counterfeit Coin + Preparation + Crystal Core

   ---

**Shaman** Turn 4 complete, turn 5 [Megafin](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Megafin)

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Unite_the_Murlocs):*** Summon 10 Murlocs.

With or without coin:

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 1x [Primalfin Totem](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Primalfin_Totem) + 1x Murloc from Totem
3. turn: 3x 1-drop Murloc + 1x Murloc from Totem
4. turn: 1x [Call in the Finishers](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Call_in_the_Finishers) + 1x Murloc from Totem
5. turn: 1x Megafin

   ---

**Warlock** Turn 4 complete, turn 5 [Nether Portal](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Nether_Portal)

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Lakkari_Sacrifice):*** Discard 6 cards.

As first Player (no coin):

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 1x [Darkshire Librarian](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Darkshire_Librarian) discards [Clutchmother Zavas](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Clutchmother_Zavas) and gets killed
3. turn: 1x Darkshire Librarian discards Clutchmother Zavas + 1x [Soulfire](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Soulfire) discards Clutchmother Zavas, Opponennt plays Arcane Golem
4. turn: 1x Soulfire, 2x [Succubus](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Succubus) every time Clutchmother Zavas discarded
5. turn: 1x Nether Portal

*edit: without Arcane Golem played by your Opponent in turn 3 or 4 you can't complete the Quest on turn 5, thanks to scenia again*

As second Player (coin):

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 1x Darkshire Librarian discards Clutchmother Zavas + Coin + 1x Soulfire discards Clutchmother Zavas
3. turn: 1x Darkshire Librarian discards Clutchmother Zavas + 1x Soulfire discards Clutchmother Zavas
4. turn: 1x [Lakkari Felhound](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Lakkari_Felhound)
5. turn: 1x Nether Portal

---

**Warrior** Turn 4 complete, turn 5 [Sulfuras](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Sulfuras)

***[Quest](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Fire_Plume%27s_Heart):*** Play 7 Taunt minions.

As first Player (no coin):

1. turn: Quest
2. turn: 2x [Shieldbearer](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Shieldbearer)
3. turn: 2x [Goldshire Footman](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Goldshire_Footman) + 1x [I know a guy](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/I_Know_a_Guy) into Shieldbearer (Opponent plays Arcane Golem, otherwise not enough Mana to complete Quest)
4. turn: 1x I know a guy into Shieldbearer + 2x Shieldbearer + 1x [Frostwolf Grunt](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Frostwolf_Grunt)
5. turn: 1x Sulfuras

As second Player (coin):

1. turn: Quest + Coin + 1x Shieldbearer
2. turn: 1x Shieldbearer + 1x Goldshire Footman
3. turn: 1x Goldshire Footman + 1x Frostwolf Grunt
4. turn: 1x Frostwolf Grunt + 1x I know a guy into Shieldbearer + 1x Shieldbearer
5. turn: 1x Sulfuras

---

Good luck! :P

Comment: Your Warlock without coin has 5 Mana on turn 4. Also Mage can simply play Primordial Glyph into 5 more Primordial Glyphs and any activatable Spell up to 2 mana for the last Glyph on turn 2 without Coin. With Coin, only a chain of 4 additional Primordial Glyphs must be discovered and the last Spell may cost up to 3 mana.

Comment: @scenia I don't get what you mean with the Warlock part, could you please explain it? To Mage, yes it is just one way, there are several more for each class. But in both variants you are not faster than turn 4 or do you have an example? Would be great! Edit: Ah, yes, you are faster in completing the Quest, thanks!

Comment: For reference, applicable 1-cost Paladin spells are [Divine Strength](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Divine_Strength), [Blessing of Wisdom](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Blessing_of_Wisdom), [Adaption](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Adaptation), [Hand of Protection](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Hand_of_Protection), [Blessing of Might](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Blessing_of_Might), [Humility](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Humility), and [Forbidden Healing](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Forbidden_Healing), though those last two are probably less-than optimal.

Comment: I like how Mage basically turns Time Warp into a 5-mana Wild Growth/Coin combination, giving one full Mana crystal.

Comment: Wow, this is indeed quite a list. Thanks for making the effort :)

Answer (score -1):

Artery's answer is great but some of the heroes could hugely benefit from **Millhouse Manastrom**:

Mage - can cast Time Warp turn 1. - Quest + cycling Primordial Glyph + Time Warp

Paladin - quest ready turn 1. - play 1-cost minion + just have some expensive card draw spells + buff minion

Warlock - can discard 2 cards on turn 1.- Quest + Malchezaar's Imp + 2 x Soulfire [or simply play quest Nether Portal turn 4]

Shaman - can play quest + Call in the Finishers twice on turn 1.

Both Shaman and Paladin still need some way of playing quest minions earlier so feel free to comment/edit.